# When scroll to a specified place, starts the function, how to reset it and start again, if we go back again to this place?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll

Below, I gave an example of a function that starts the animation when we scroll down to `300 pixels`.

At the end of the round elements are transformed into ovals and red block coming to the right side.

**Question:** how do I make this function reset if the scroll up to the position less than 300 pixels, and start again if you omit to position more than `300 pixels`?

```js
i = 0;

function ring() {
  if (i < 1) {
    $('.ring').delay(500).animate({ //1
        left: 287,
      },
      500, 'linear');
    $('.ring').delay(500).animate({ //2
        left: 500,
      },
      500, 'linear');
    $('.ring').delay(500).animate({ //2.1
        left: 594,
      },
      200, 'linear')
  };
  if (i < 1) {
    $('.views-row-1').animate({ //9
        width: 140,
        top: -14,
        boxShadow: "0 0 8px",

      },
      500);
    $('.views-row-1').delay(500).animate({ //9
        width: 115,
        top: 0,
        boxShadow: "0 0 0",
      },
      500);
    $('.views-row-2').delay(1000).animate({ //9
        width: 140,
        top: -14,
        boxShadow: "0 0 8px",
      },
      500);
    $('.views-row-2').delay(500).animate({ //9
        width: 115,
        top: 0,
        boxShadow: "0 0 0",
      },
      500);
    $('.views-row-3').delay(2000).animate({ //9
        width: 140,
        top: -14,
        boxShadow: "0 0 8px",
      },
      500)
  };

  return i++;
}


function scr() {
  var top = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (top > 300) {
    ring();
  };
}
$(window).scroll(scr);
```

```css
.views-row-1,
.views-row-2,
.views-row-3 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.views-row-2 {
  left: 100px;
}
.views-row-3 {
  left: 185px;
}
.ring {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  background: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 4;
}
.parent {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 60px;
}
body {
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Start to scroll down
<div class="parent">
  <div class="ring"></div>
  <div class="views-row-1"></div>
  <div class="views-row-2"></div>
  <div class="views-row-3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a function to reset that.
You can't have it automatically done.

to do that, just set the values for *views-row-1*, *views-row-2*, *views-row-3* and *ring* to the initial state.

for example, **ring** would have the *left* property set to zero again, the **views-row-*** would have their width set to 60px, etc.

Comment: that is, I need to write a function that returns all the items in the initial position, but how to do that when you scroll to a certain place again earned first function?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your comment, but you could add this to the function _scr()_ that you have. so you can put another if for top < 300, for example.  and if you want it to be called only if has reached 300 at least once, you can put a flag like **hasAnimated** so you would check _if (top < 300 && hasAnimated)_